# How to define different schemas in Swagger

Tags: api, swagger

I am looking to use Swagger to document our apis, but I am not sure how with my current use case.

Basically there is a ui that creates a schema and then sends it downstream. I am trying to document the input, but the schema can change based on different values of one of the key.Say the "type" is x, then the schema is:

```
{
  "type":"x",
  "info":{
    "key_x":""
  }
}
```

And if the "type" is z, then the schema is:

```
{
  "type":"z",
  "info":{
    "key_z":""
  }
}
```

So is there a way to do this? I was looking at maps, but couldn't see a way to route different schemas based on value.